# Electron Global shortcut find browser instance

Tags: electron, keyboard-shortcuts

Hi guys I'm using e[lectron-globalshortcut](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts#global-shortcuts)

I would like to override the default shortcut 'CTRL+W' for browser windows since I have a few of them like popups.

The problem that i'm having is that when  I define global shortcut like this:

```
 globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+W', () => {
    console.log('CommandOrControl+W is pressed')
  })
```

How do I get on what Browser instance it is? How could I get a reference to correct Browser window

Answer (score 1):

When you create your BrowserWindow, you do it like this

```
const window = new BrowserWindow({.../*Your options here*/});
```

So, you can bind the register to this ***window*** variable:

```
window.on("focus", () => {
globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+W', () => {
    console.log('CommandOrControl+W is pressed');
  })
});

window.on("blur", () => {
globalShortcut.unregisterAll()
});
```

Also, it is recommended to call the registers inside ***ready*** app event. And if you have more than one BrowserWindow, the current focused one can be detected with

```
BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()
```

Please refer to https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window